# Illegal input into ODEINT

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

given the following system of equations:

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \alpha P(1-\frac{P}{K}) - \beta P I$$

$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta P I - \rho I$$

i was given a task to numerically solve the system of ODEs and plot the solution for varying parameters. but for some reason I get this error

> ```
> /home/gideon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:16: 
>  RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
>  app.launch_new_instance()
>  /home/gideon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247: 
>  ODEintWarning: Illegal input detected (internal error). Run with full_output = 1 to get 
>  quantitative information.
>  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
> ```

could someone assist in solving this issue. here is my code

```
'''
 x[0]  : P(t). population not infected
 x[1]  : I(t). population Infected
 k     : population carrying capacity
 alpha : growth rate
 rho   : death rate
 beta  : infection rate
 t     : time
'''

k = 2
alpha = 2
rho = 1
beta = 5

xprime = lambda  x,k,alpha,rho,beta,t: np.array([alpha*x[0]*(1-(x[0]/k))-beta*x[0]*x[1],
                                            beta*x[0]*x[1]-rho*x[1]])
x0 = np.array([(4/5)*k,k/5])
t = np.linspace(0,20,50)
x = odeint(xprime,x0,t,args=(k,alpha,rho,beta,))



y1 = x[:,0]
y2 = x[:,1]


plt.plot(t,y1,'b',label='P(t)')
plt.plot(t,y2,'g--',label='I(t)')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I got it. the issue is that variables must be defined before parameters